# Проблема с форматом "Format_Mono" в Qt

Tags: qt, qimage

Обнаружил некорректную работу класса `QImage`.
Вот отрывок кода:

```
QImage imgImg;
pixImg.load( imgName );   //JPG 2160*1560
imgImg = pixImg.toImage();
imgImg.bytesPerLine();   //8640 Format ARGB
imgImg = imgImg.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Mono);
imgImg.bytesPerLine();   //272  Format Mono
```

Суть в том, что после преобразования изображения в Format_Mono появляются лишних 2 байта (272 вместо 270 (270*8 = 2160)). До преобразования все в порядке, т.к 8640 / 4 = 2160. Я подразумеваю, что после преобразования в каждом байте находится 8 бит, определяющих цвет 8 пикселей. Но эта теория не сходится с реальностью. Знающие люди - подскажите :)

Comment: Какое значение этих байт? 272 нацело делится на 4, так что это может быть добивка строки нулями до длины, кратной четырём байтам.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю. 272 это количество байт монохромного изображения. Каждый байт описывает 8 пикселей(1-черный, 0-белый). Поэтому можно предложить , что чтобы получить ширину в пикселях нужно 272 * 8 = 2176 != 2160. Т.е 2 байта(16 пикселей) здесь явно лишние

Comment: Эти два последних байта не принадлежат изображению. Конвертер закодировал одну строку изображения и получившийся массив добил нулями до размера, кратного четырём байтам. Затем взял следующую строку и также добил её нулями. Поэтому в изображении и хранятся явно как `bytesPerLine()`, так и `width()` — одно из другого не выводится как раз из-за этих «хвостов».

Comment: Я вас понял) Как приду домой проверю эту теорию)

Comment: Да, действительно, вы были правы. Данные изображения и вправду выравниваются по 4 байтам построчно. Но для чего это?

Comment: Причина чисто историческая — ранние Интелы сильно проседали по производительности при чтении невыровненных данных.

Comment: Буду знать, спасибо за помощь!